# String Method Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want the function/method to return a meaning less string made from the alphabets of the given string.**How to call the function?**
Example:
Input: America
Output: Aca or aca**

I have tried this:

```
var meaningless = function(){
s = this.toLowerCase();
for (var i=0, i < s.length, i++)
return s[s.length] + s[i] + s[0] + "is a meaningless" ;
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
var meaningless = function(){
var s= "HELLO WORLD";
s = this.toLowerCase();
for (var i=0, i < s.length, i++)
return s.charAt(s.length); + s.charAt(i); + s.charAt(0); + "is a meaningless" ;
}
```

Comment: Your for loop syntax is not correct at the very least `for (var i=0; i < s.length; i++)`. Other than that, `this.toLowerCase` will be undefined and your `for` loop is redundant when it only contains a `return`

Comment: to add the method to string, you'll need to add it to it's prototype

Comment: tried this now but getting error:

var meaningless = function(){
return s[s.length] + s[3] + s[0] + "is a meaningless" ;
}
meaningless("icecream")
VM277:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: s is not defined(…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your function, as RGraham mentioned, the for loop is unnecessary, since you're only "looping" through once, before you return (therefor breaking out of the loop and the function).  If you were actually using the for loop however, the syntax is wrong. You should use semicolons instead of commas.  You're also returning `s.charAt(s.length);` and nothing following. The semicolon ends that statement.  There is also no `charAt` the length - string arrays start at 0, so the last character is `s.length - 1`.

See how I reworked it below.

```js
function meaningless(s) {
  s = s.toLowerCase();
  if (s.length >= 3) {
    return "&quot;" + s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2] + s[0] + "&quot; is a meaningless";
  }

  return s;
}

// THE FOLLOWING IS FOR DEMONSTRATION ONLY
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = meaningless("America");
```

```html
<!-- DEMONSTRATION-ONLY HTML -->
<div id="demo"></div>
```

A more interactive demo of the function:

```js
function meaningless(s) {
  s = s.toLowerCase();
  if (s.length >= 3) {
    return s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2] + s[0];
  }

  return s;
}

// THE FOLLOWING IS FOR DEMONSTRATION ONLY

var inputEle = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = makeInputMeaningless;
inputEle.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) { // Enter key was pressed while in the input field
    makeInputMeaningless();
  }
};

function makeInputMeaningless() {
  var meaninglessValue = meaningless(inputEle.value);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = meaninglessValue;
}
```

```html
<!-- DEMONSTRATION-ONLY HTML -->
<p>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Make Meaningless</button>
</p>
<p><strong>Meaningless result: </strong><span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: thank you very much!! This helped!

how should i modify the code to run it in the Google Chrome console?
the demo id does not work. is there a normal way of calling the function in chrome console?

Comment: The demo id was just for demonstration purposes.  The function itself should work.  You can call it like I am, just don't place in the innerHTML of an element.  i.e. `meaningless("America");`

Comment: If this works for you, please mark this as the answer.